# rigidbody.velocity not working with transform. up

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, rotation

[image: here is the direction of transform.up seen in debug]

[image: full code]

[image: code for the jumping script, but character is jumping straight up, even with the direction, jump force is normal float]

[image: unity prefab]

[image: unity prefab]

I have checked multiple times that the rotation is being loaded by the rigid body and rotation isn't frozen. but it will just jump straight up. Also tried to see if the sleeping mode on the rigid body was the problem, but did not seem to be the case.

I have looked this up on multiple searches and even the unity documentation has this way of doing it; https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-up.html, so i cant help but think its a problem in unity and how i have my sprite.

Comment: [**Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: on the Rigidbody there is a CompositeCollider .. does that mean the other object you show us (HERO) is a different one than the one that has the rigidbody attached? .. in general rather use `body.velocity = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, body.rotation) * jumpForce;`

Answer (score 0):

your first line of code in update() breaks your jump direction:

```
body.velocity = Vector2(Input.Axis("Horizontal") * speed, body.velocity.y)
```

It means, that you will set velocity.x to 0 every frame, if you don't press horizontal movement button.

To fix this, you can, for example, add velocity to existing velocity value:

```
body.velocity += Vector2.right * (Input.Axis("Horizontal") * speed);
```